# Good sources of examples for inspiration?

Tags: typography, templates

A bit of an OT-question from a newbie I'm afraid...  I just hope to find some entusiasts here who may know a source.  Here goes...

Are there any good sources of sample-documents that is suitable as inspiration?  Preferbly online, but books (especially free ebooks) will also do.  Old, handwritten, typeset/printed etc. samples, is also welcome.

Letters/envelopes, resumes/cv's, business/calling-cards, invitation, letters of introduction, business-letters, applications -- all of interest.

I'm not as interested in ready-made templates, but more of examples -- of the text (language, grammar, form), the layout, the fonts/penmanship -- of various writings over time (but mostly modern), as a source of inspiration.  I guess images (jpeg) would be the most obvouous way to present such stuff online.  So, any recomendations for sites or books for inspiration?

(That said, recomendations for websites for *really good* sources of templates for TeX/LaTeX and LyX -- and perhaps for Scribus, Open/Libre-Office and MS-Word -- would be welcommed too.)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/1358#1358